# TimeoutException in test using BehaviorSubject - BLoC

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart, bloc

I created a simple Bloc that makes use of `BehaviorSubject` and I'm trying to test its emitted values, but I keep getting `TimeoutException` during the test or error in order when I swap the streams added.

**The bloc**

```
class ApplicationBloc extends BlocBase{

  final _appTitle = BehaviorSubject<String>();
  Function(String)  get changeTitle => (title) => _appTitle.sink.add(title);
  Stream<String> get apptitle => _appTitle.stream;

  ApplicationBloc(){
   // _appTitle.sink.add('title');
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _appTitle.close();
  }
}
```

**The Test**

```
 test('check title correct', (){

        //works
       /* appBloc.changeTitle('hi');
        expect(appBloc.apptitle, emitsInAnyOrder(['hi']));*/

        //doesn't work
        appBloc.changeTitle('hi');
        appBloc.changeTitle('hello');
        expect(appBloc.apptitle, emitsInOrder(['hi', 'hello']));
  });
```

When the title stream emits a single item, it works okay. But when it emits multiple items, it times out. 
This is the error I get when the emittion order is swapped

> ERROR: Expected: should do the following in order:
>             * emit an event that 'hi'
>             * emit an event that 'hello'   Actual: '>    Which: emitted * hello
>               which didn't emit an event that 'hi' because it emitted an event that is different.
>                     Expected: hi
>                       Actual: hello
>                                ^
>                      Differ at offset 1

**NOTE:** Everything works as I expect when I change the `BehaviorSubject` to `StreamController`

Answer (score 0):

the timeout part may have been a bug, cause today with RxDart 0.24.1, there is no timeout anymore.

but the test doesn't pass still, because `BehaviorSubject` is only returning the latest value when `expect` subscribes to `.apptitle` to listen for values.

for a subject to return everything it was given, use a `ReplaySubject`.